# Stopping 'stepdown' effect in responsive mode

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm having trouble aligning 3 sets of image and text in a sidebar on a WordPress site. I've created a custom CSS class to float the images left as I wanted the accompanying text to wrap around the image using:

```
.floatLeft{float:left; margin-right:5px}
```

This works fine in desktop mode:

[image: Desktop Mode]

But when in responsive mode I get the stepdown effect with the images re-aligning themselves:

[image: Stepdown in responsive mode]

Ideally, I want the images to stay aligned left until the width is too small where they will re-align in order. I've also messed around with the `inline`/`inline-block` styles but I'm having no luck.

This is my code (also available on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/liheruvodu/edit?html,css,output)):

```css
.floatLeft {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="pgc-26-1-1" class="panel-grid-cell">
    <div id="panel-26-1-1-0" class="so-panel widget widget_text panel-first-child panel-last-child widgetopts-SO" data-index="2">
      <div class="textwidget">
        <h2 align: top>Key Messages</h2>
        <p><strong><img class="floatLeft alignnone wp-image-1754" src="https://placehold.it/225x281/" alt="" width="225" height="281" /></strong></p>
        <p><strong>Water</strong> is vital for drinking, growing crops and supporting industry. Most of us can reduce the amount of water that we waste, saving ourselves money, and benefiting rivers and internationally important wetlands. We also have the
          option
          <br /> to increase the amount of rainfall we capture or encourage it to go into the ground &#8211; using sustainable drainage systems &#8211; to replenish our vital groundwater aquifers.</p>
        <p><img class="floatLeft alignnone wp-image-1765" src="https://placehold.it/225x281/" alt="" width="225" height="281" /></p>
        <p><strong>Rivers and wetlands</strong> provide enjoyment for many people whether angling, canoeing, watching wildlife or enjoying picturesque views. Rivers receive our waste water and many have been modified for flood defence, milling and navigation
          purposes. There are opportunities in the upper, non-tidal areas to restore river reaches and even reconnect the floodplain &#8211; using low-cost techniques &#8211; where no flood risk to property occurs.</p>
        <p><img class="floatLeft alignnone wp-image-1766" src="https://placehold.it/225x281/" alt="" width="225" height="281" /></p>
        <p><strong>Land</strong> is essential for food and fuel, but it also provides other services to society including flood protection, freshwater provision, wildlife habitat and recreation. Managing land for these other services in targeted marginal
          locations, while supporting sustainable agriculture across the wider landscape, is the key to success.</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Tom, you should add a demo of the actual thing (with HTML and CSS) so we could see the problem (read [mcve] for hints), that would make it easier for us to help you (it seems you need a `clear:both` but without seeing your code it's impossible to say where). Complete the [tour] and read [ask] for more information.

Comment: I've added a jsbin to the OP: http://jsbin.com/liheruvodu/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your comment until now (you can tag people so they get notifications by putting an @ before their name)

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your code, the thing that you need to do is make sure that the images don't share the same horizontal space. For that, you can do `clear:left` or `clear:both` (as I suggested in the question comments). But you wouldn't apply them to the image itself, but to the `p` that contains it.

An easy way would be to add a class to the `p` that contains the image and add the `clear:both` to that class, which would require some easy HTML changes. If you don't want to change the HTML, you can select the `p` that contains the image as they are always the even children of the parent container, so you could do `nth-child(2n)` like this:

```css
.floatLeft {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.textwidget p:nth-child(2n) {
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="pgc-26-1-1" class="panel-grid-cell">
    <div id="panel-26-1-1-0" class="so-panel widget widget_text panel-first-child panel-last-child widgetopts-SO" data-index="2">
      <div class="textwidget">
        <h2 align: top>Key Messages</h2>
        <p><strong><img class="floatLeft alignnone wp-image-1754" src="https://placehold.it/225x281/" alt="" width="225" height="281" /></strong></p>
        <p><strong>Water</strong> is vital for drinking, growing crops and supporting industry. Most of us can reduce the amount of water that we waste, saving ourselves money, and benefiting rivers and internationally important wetlands. We also have the
          option
          <br /> to increase the amount of rainfall we capture or encourage it to go into the ground &#8211; using sustainable drainage systems &#8211; to replenish our vital groundwater aquifers.</p>
        <p><img class="floatLeft alignnone wp-image-1765" src="https://placehold.it/225x281/" alt="" width="225" height="281" /></p>
        <p><strong>Rivers and wetlands</strong> provide enjoyment for many people whether angling, canoeing, watching wildlife or enjoying picturesque views. Rivers receive our waste water and many have been modified for flood defence, milling and navigation
          purposes. There are opportunities in the upper, non-tidal areas to restore river reaches and even reconnect the floodplain &#8211; using low-cost techniques &#8211; where no flood risk to property occurs.</p>
        <p><img class="floatLeft alignnone wp-image-1766" src="https://placehold.it/225x281/" alt="" width="225" height="281" /></p>
        <p><strong>Land</strong> is essential for food and fuel, but it also provides other services to society including flood protection, freshwater provision, wildlife habitat and recreation. Managing land for these other services in targeted marginal
          locations, while supporting sustainable agriculture across the wider landscape, is the key to success.</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```